# Circular image as button PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I'm trying to create a circular button with an image.
So far I've been able to create a circular button and a button with an image background but I haven't been able to combine the two.

Here is my current code:

```
import sys
import PyQt5.QtWidgets


class Window(PyQt5.QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # setting title
        self.setWindowTitle("Python ")

        # setting geometry
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)

        # calling method
        self.UiComponents()

        # showing all the widgets
        self.show()

    # method for widgets
    def UiComponents(self):
        button = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QPushButton("CLICK", self)
        button.setGeometry(200, 150, 100, 100)

        # Background img and circular
        button.setStyleSheet('''border-radius : 5;
        border : 2px solid black
        background-image : url(image.png);
        ''')

        # adding action to a button
        button.clicked.connect(self.clickme)

    # action method
    def clickme(self):
        print("pressed")



App = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: Note that the above code won't work, as you're missing a `;` at the end of the second line of the stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt documentation has a section exactly [about this topic](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#qpushbutton-and-images):

> When styling a QPushButton, it is often desirable to use an image as the button graphic. It is common to try the background-image property, but this has a number of drawbacks: For instance, the background will often appear hidden behind the button decoration, because it is not considered a background. In addition, if the button is resized, the entire background will be stretched or tiled, which does not always look good.
>
> It is better to use the border-image property, as it will always display the image, regardless of the background (you can combine it with a background if it has alpha values in it), and it has special settings to deal with button resizing.

So, you must ensure that you're using a square (not rectangular) image with the circle margins right at the edges, and use `border-image` instead of `background-image` (which tiles the image if it's smaller than the button size); note that you should *not* set any border in the stylesheet.

```
    button.setStyleSheet('''
        border-image: url(image.png);
        ''')
```

You obviously need to always use the same value for both the height and the width of the button, possibly by using `setFixedSize()`, otherwise if you add the button to a layout it will not be circular any more.